# How can get image from http response in java?

Tags: java, sockets, http, networking

I want to get an image from a server by making http request manually . I make a connection , create a http request wait for , get the http reply from server and then i want data inside it.I separated header from data and saved it into a file with ".jpeg" extension . But my .jpeg file could not be opened. What can i do ?

Note: i cant use any plugin or libraries . I just can process on http request!

Here my code :

```
try (Socket socket = new Socket("ceit.aut.ac.ir", 80)) {

        // send an HTTP request to the web server
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        outToServer.writeBytes("GET /~94131090/CN1_Project_Files/flower.jpeg  HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        outToServer.writeBytes("Host: ceit.aut.ac.ir:80\r\n");
        outToServer.writeBytes("Connection: Close\r\n");
        outToServer.writeBytes("Content-Type:image/*\r\n");
        outToServer.writeBytes("\r\n");
        // Receive an HTTP reply from the web server
        boolean loop = true;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (loop) {
            if (inFromServer.ready()) {
                int i = 0;
                while (i != -1) {


                    i = inFromServer.read();
                    sb.append((char) i);
                }
                loop = false;
            }
        }

        //Download Image
        String data = separate(sb.toString());
        //???

        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here my separate function :

```
public String separate(String str){
    String msg = str;

    int index = msg.indexOf("close");

    // "close" and blank end of http response line including \r\n
    // 3(close) + 2(\r) + 2 (\n) + 2 (\r) + 2 (\n) = 4 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 6

    return msg.substring(index+11);

}
```

Comment: You need to show us  the code extracting the body (about where you have `//???` now)

Comment: ok I added the separate function

Comment: Not sure why you are looking for "close" for the end of headers, or what the magic number 11 is about. You might want to parse the response according to the [Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setInstanceFollowRedirects-boolean-)

Comment: You cannot use a Reader to read a binary HTTP response body, like an image;  you must use an InputStream for that.  Also, in Java, a String does *not* hold bytes;  it holds characters, which do not correspond directly to bytes.  You should never attempt to store bytes in a String or StringBuilder.  Instead, read the response from an InputStream, and write each byte directly to a file or add it to a ByteBuffer.